# Custom elements added from AJAX are not working

Tags: html, dom, custom-element

I understand that custom-elements are very new technology.

Following code displays different things in Webkit browsers and Firefox (with `dom.webcomponents.enabled`).

I am not understand: Why adding custom elements, loaded with AJAX, create in Webkit browsers a HTMLUnknownElement instead of custom element? Is this a bug? Chrome says that it has full support of custom elements. Firefox instead, has support behind a flag.

This is `index.html`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html><head></head><body>
<script>
var proto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);
proto.attachedCallback = function() { this.innerHTML = "Custom elements work :-)"; }
var TLoad = document.registerElement('t-load', { prototype: proto });
</script>
<t-load>Custom element are not working :-(</t-load>
<script>
var tload = new TLoad();
tload.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Custom element are not working :-('));
var where = document.querySelector('t-load');
where.parentNode.insertBefore(tload, where);

tload = document.createElement('t-load');
tload.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Custom element are not working :-('));
where.parentNode.insertBefore(tload, where);

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'loaded.xml', false);
request.send(null);
var result = document.adoptNode(request.responseXML.documentElement);
console.log(result);
where.parentNode.insertBefore(result, where);
</script>
</body></html>
```

This is `loaded.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<t-load>Custom element are not working :-(</t-load>
</div>
```

Output is: (Chrome. Firefox has other output)

```
Custom elements work :-)Custom elements work :-)
Custom elements are not working :-(
Custom elements work :-)
```

Comment: noone knows about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `importNode` instead of `adpotNode`. Example:

```
var result = document.importNode(request.responseXML.documentElement, true);
```

Comment: Good question! I don't know. I didn't know the adoptNode before... Maybe with adoptNode the node is not re-created so Custom Element cannot see it in the HTML node list. Or maybe it's because of the different nature of XML and HTML element. Who knows? The ones that developed the JS engines. Online documentation is not clear.